# How can I work out what curdate() in MySQL is returning?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to know when I write a query like

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE expiry > curdate()
```

How can I work out what the `curdate()` is returning? I just switched servers of a site and it appears to be throwing it out, by perhaps returning a different `curdate()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

Comment: Sometimes it really is that simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), CURDATE():

> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD  format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.